# React - filter by object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to filter object by property but I can't make it work.

**Data in the object are structured like so:**

[image]

I am fetching data by the UID and then mapping all the items from that object but I can't make the filter work.

**Render method looks like so:**

```js
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {Object.keys(this.state.dataGoal)
          .filter(key => key.main == true)
          .map( (key, index) => {
            return <div key={key}>
                     <h1>{this.state.dataGoal[key].name}</h1>
                     <p>{this.state.dataGoal[key].main}</p>
                   </div>
          })}
      </div>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for any help,
Jakub

Comment: What is `this.state.dataGoal`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns the `keys` of that object, meaning that it returns an array of strings with every key in that object.

```
obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };
Object.keys(obj); // ['a', 'b']
```

So to access the value of that property you have to access it using that key, in your case it would be something like this:

```
filter(key => this.state.dataGoal[key].main == true)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that is the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `this.state.dataGoal` is the object from posted goals array, then your filter is wrong. Should be:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.dataGoal)
  .filter(key => this.state.dataGoal[key].main === true)
  .map((key, index) => {
    return <div key={key}>
             <h1>{this.state.dataGoal[key].name}</h1>
             <p>{this.state.dataGoal[key].main}</p>
           </div>
  })}
```

Note, that now it's `.filter(key => this.state.dataGoal[key].main === true)` because key is the string, something like `Khasdfasdfasdfasdfads` and you want to access `goal` object by this key in order to check its `main` property.